# JBoss web application not connecting to RMI server

Tags: java, jboss, rmi

I had a web application running in Apache Tomcat which was a client for a RMI Server that I have running and it worked fine.

Now I migrated that web application to JBoss 5.1, and everything is working except the connection with the RMI Server, so I suppose that the problem comes with the configuration of JBoss.

The code of the client is the following:

```
//RMI
System.setProperty("java.security.policy","file:/C:/policy.txt");
//policy.txt: grant { permission java.security.AllPermission; };

System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());

ControladorMails c = null;

try {
    c = (ControladorMails) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost/GestorMails");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the exception I get:

> java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:230)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
>       at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:322)
>       at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
>       at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:84)
>       at controller.ControladorUsuarios.addNotificacion(ControladorUsuarios.java:97)
>       at dao.TestDAO.main(TestDAO.java:73)

I have been looking for a solution but i don't find anything solving the problem. Maybe the problem is related to the JNDI Port, which is set to 1099, and i have read that rmiregistry uses 1099 by default. But I have been trying to change the ports in both of them and it isn't working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The failure you are getting isn't with the 'RMI server' at all. It is with the RMI Registry. You are using Naming.lookup() where you should be using something JBoss-specific. As the exception suggests.